# What are those 6 extra studs for in 42000 Grand Prix racer?

Tags: design

I recently purchased a set, Technic 42000 Grand Prix Racer, that I am very happy with. However, I am perplexed by the fact that the set came with 6 extra transparent 1x1 round plates (studs).[image]

As you can see, this was clearly not a mistake, as they are shown in the instruction manual. So my question is, does anyone know what these are for? My guess was that perhaps the Designer is signing his/her name to the set in a quirky way. Can anyone explain?

Comment: [Sariel's video explains it](https://youtu.be/bq-nColRWj0?t=281) - they aren't used in the A model, but if you scroll down into the [comments](http://content.screencast.com/users/slapshot136/folders/Jing/media/7aad6afe-ba55-4337-b4a6-5475bcde628e/2015-07-16_2314.png), it's explained that they are for the B model

Comment: @user2813274 - You should probably post this as an answer - I know we prefer longer answers if possible, but I think there's not much more to it here ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Sariel's assembly video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bq-nColRWj0&feature=youtu.be&t=281) shows that he ends up not using those 6 studs for the car assembly

but wait! if you scroll down into the comments:

[image: http://content.screencast.com/users/slapshot136/folders/Jing/media/7aad6afe-ba55-4337-b4a6-5475bcde628e/2015-07-16_2314.png]

he explains that the pieces are used for the B-model:
[image: B-model race truck, with 6 studs for headlights]

Comment: Then why show them at all if they are not used ???? I spent time searching for answers myself. It must have been a mistake. There were other left over pieces that you assume are used for the other model and they were not shown as part of this model. Very strange.

Comment: @JonStephens my bet is - to show you they are not connected and you haven't missed anything.